# Drawing a stationary background

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, 3d

In my program, I am trying to use an image and draw it as a stationary background. The foreground does have some models loaded inside a camera and runnig fine.

However, when I apply a background image, the whole model and other objects don't appear and I can only see the background image appearing over the screen.

I did the disable the Depth_Test before drawing the background and then re-enabled it before drawing the model.

```
glDisbale(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
bgImage.draw(0,0); //draw the background image. Width and height parameters previously while initializing image

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
cam.begin();
//stuff drawn inside
cam.end();
```

Also tried clearing the `Depth Buffer/Depth Color bit` after the `bgImage.draw` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable depth writes so that the background doesn't hogs the depth buffer.

```
glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
background();
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

Or you simply clear only the depth buffer after drawing the background:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
background();  // instead of clearing the color
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: Or draw the background further away.